# SSRS - Grouping on the same level

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2016

attempting to make a report with-in SSRS, but have leaf nodes at varied depths. wondering if there is a good way to present this data (a tree perhaps?) with roll-up summations and drilldown?

2 tables of data:

```
Account   | Amount
100001    |    1
100002    |    2
100003    |    3
```

```
Account   |    Parent Account
100001    |    100RM_ER
100002    |    100RM_ER
100RM_ER  |    100RM
100003    |    100RM
100RM     |    INV
```

Best I can think of is creating a query that produces results like this with 6 fields and putting into a table with 6 headers.  seems clunky and when i have a leaf at a not-so-deep level (like 100003) the display gets weird with expanding a bunch of null points.

```
Lvl0    |    Lvl1   |   Lvl2    |   Lvl3    |   Leaf    |   Amount
INV     |   100RM   |   Null    |   Null    |   100003  |   3
INV     |   100RM   |   100RM_ER|   Null    |   100002  |   2
INV     |   100RM   |   100RM_ER|   Null    |   100001  |   1
```

Comment: if expand and collapse is what you are after.. have a look at this.. https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/9/19/expand-or-collapse-all-grouped-items-on-ssrs-report.html

Comment: thanks - i think i'm asking the wrong question.  will rephrase

Comment: Anyone stumbling onto this - https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/860824/Using-Recursive-Hierarchy-Group-in-SSRS